# What does the vertical axis of the Kuznets curve depict (mathematically)?

Tags: macroeconomics, inequality

I do not understand what does the word "inequality" means on the vertical axis of the Kuznets curve. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Kuznet talked about *income inequality*. In this context it is often measured by the Gini coefficient or the [Kuznet ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuznets_curve#Kuznets_ratio), but basically any measure of income inequality would do, since Kuznet's hypothesis is merely a qualitative one.